# How to deploy Play 2 application to Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to deploy Play 2 application to Apache Tomcat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Play 2.0 doesn't natively support Tomcat deployments, but there is a plugin that will create a WAR package to deploy on Tomcat: https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/

Comment: I have used this plugin to generate war for Play2.4 and successfully deployed it on tomcat 8. I have a question though that can i used this plugin for a Maven based play project?